# stop click.trigger() from firing on a particular nested element

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am trying to use click.tigger() to change the mode of the template to editable. Problem is I have a image gallery inside this template that I don't want click.trigger to fire on.

app.js:

```
<div click.trigger="enableEdit()">
    <response containerless></response>
</div>
```

response.html:

```
<template>
    <div>
       ...
       <gallery></gallery> <-- I want this to still be able to fire
       <button click.trigger="save()">save</button> <-- I want this to work as well but they wont with "enableEdit()" above attached.
    </div>
</template>
```

Gallery.js:

```
attached() {
    const carousel = new Flickity(this.gallery, {
      cellAlign: 'left',
      contain: true,
      lazyLoad: true,
    });
  }
```

Once I click the trigger it does work and enable edit. The gallery is using a Plugin called Flickity. Above I show how I instantiated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider putting the click binding on a sibling element.  Avoid stopping events from bubbling because it can make your code brittle/not-portable.

A quick fix would be to inspect the click event's [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). Find out if the click originated from your `gallery` element or one of it's children.

```html
<div click.trigger="enableEdit($event.target)">
  <response containerless></response>
</div>
```

```js
enableEdit(target) {
  if (target.nodeName === 'gallery' || target.closest('gallery') !== null) {
    // it's the gallery element or one of it's children... get out of here...
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

*note:  [`Element.closest(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) isn't [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest) in Internet Explorer yet. Use a [simple polyfill](https://github.com/jonathantneal/closest/blob/master/closest.js) to be safe.*

Comment: That $event.target is jquery no? Is there a vanilla approach to passing over the target or grabbing the target?

Comment: `$event` is an aurelia property you can bind to in `delegate` and `trigger` bindings that will give you access to the DOM event that was fired.